# Sanity.io webhook with body params

Tags: sanity

I added a webhook to Sanity and it works as expected, but I would like to pass a parameter in the body for {branch:"develop"} and I do not see an input field.

I have tried appending ?branch=develop to the url, but that does not work.

Any ideas on how to include this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to add this into your projection? Something like the following would return everything, plus `'branch': 'develop'`:

```
{
  ...,
  'branch': 'develop',
}
```